# JQuery .append list items not triggering a script when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a page that loads data from an `XML file` that populates an HTML `unordered list`. An `unordered list` is used to make the gallery from the tutorial on [this page](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/). Unfortunately, the created thumbnails do not trigger the javascript which creates the expanding preview.

The javascript should be activated when the user clicks on an anchor in the `unordered list`.

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this issue would be great.

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });

    function xmlParser(xml) {
        $('#load').fadeOut();
        $(xml).find("painting").each(function () {
            $("ul#og-grid").append('<li> <a href="http://google.com/" data-largesrc="images/' + $(this).find("image").text() + '"   data-title="' + $(this).find("title").text() + '" ' + '<>' + '<img src="images/thumbs/' + $(this).find("image").text() + '"  alt="img01"/> </a> <li> ');
            $(".painting").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Should `.find("painting")` be `.find('.painting')`?

Comment: the "painting" is searching the xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the click event. You can do this whilst populating your *li* or after. I would do the following

```
$(xml).find("painting").each(function () {
    $('<li> <a href="http://google.com/" data-largesrc="images/' + $(this).find("image").text() + '"   data-title="' + $(this).find("title").text() + '" ' + '<>' + '<img src="images/thumbs/' + $(this).find("image").text() + '"  alt="img01"/> </a> <li> ')
        .click(yourClickFunction)
        .appendTo('ul#og-grid');
    $(".painting").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Don't forget to change **yourClickFunction**.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

use this line for click event

```
$(document).on('click', 'element-selector', function () {
   // Do Stuff Here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following JS code for this

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul#og-grid li', function () {
   // Do Stuff Here
});
```